# No Method Error: undefined method `find_each' for User:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I wrote a scheduler function that automatically checks the if a user's free trial has ended, then automatically upgrades them to a paid subscription. The problem is that when I try to run the task from the command line the following error occurs:

> No Method Error: undefined method `find_each' for User:Class

```
task :process_trial_accounts => :environment do
  puts "Processing Trial Users"
   User.find_each do |user|

plan_id  = MailFunnelsUser.get_user_plan(user.client_id)
if plan_id == -99

  products = Infusionsoft.data_query('SubscriptionPlan', 100, 0, {}, [:Id, :PlanPrice])

  product = products.select { |product| product['Id'] == 2 }[0]

  unless product

  end

  price = product['PlanPrice']

  cardId = 0
  current_year = Date.today.strftime('%Y')
  current_month = Date.today.strftime('%m')
  creditCardId = Infusionsoft.data_query('CreditCard',
                                         100,
                                         0,
                                         {'ContactId' => user.clientid, 'ExpirationYear' => '~>=~' + current_year, 'Status' => 3},
                                         [:Id, :ContactId, :ExpirationMonth, :ExpirationYear]
  ).each do |creditCard|

    if Integer(creditCard['ExpirationYear']) == Integer(current_year)
      if Integer(creditCard['ExpirationMonth']) >= Integer(current_month)

        cardId = creditCard['Id']
      end
    else

      cardId = creditCard['Id']
    end
  end

  if cardId != 0

    subscription_id = Infusionsoft.invoice_add_recurring_order(user.clientid, true, 2, 4, cardId, 0, 0)


    invoice_id = Infusionsoft.invoice_create_invoice_for_recurring(subscription_id)

    upgrade_response = Infusionsoft.invoice_charge_invoice(invoice_id, "Automatic Upgrade to 1000 Subscriber Tier", cardId, 4, false)

    if upgrade_response[:Successful]
      # Tag for 1000 sub tier level plan
      new_tier_level_tag = 106

      # Tags to remove from user
      trial_ended_tag = 145
      failed_payment_tag = 120

      # Remove Tags from user for failed payment and Trial ended
      Infusionsoft.contact_remove_from_group(user.clientid, trial_ended_tag)
      Infusionsoft.contact_remove_from_group(user.clientid, failed_payment_tag)


      # Add tag to user for 1000 subscribers tier level
      Infusionsoft.contact_add_to_group(user.clientid, new_tier_level_tag)


    end

  end

else
  next
end

 end





end
```

My application is hosted on heroku and I'm trying to run the job through there. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `find_each` method is `ActiveRecord` method, so your User class must be inherited from ActiveRecord. Are you sure you use this ORM ?

Comment: Please provide User class code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_each` method is `ActiveRecord` method, which means that User class must be inherited from ActiveRecord. In case you're not using this kind of ORM, you cannot use `find_each`.

Would be much easier if you do provide your `User` class codebase.

Cheers